# Global settings object in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm still finding my way around Laravel and not sure where this particularly functionality would fit in best.

I have a table called settings, which stores key|value pairs. When queried, I end up with an array of settings. I want to get these settings at the beginning of every page load, once, and then use it throughout the site.

Where would be the best place to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In `AppServiceProvider` boot method.Using  `View::share`

```
public function boot()
{
      
    $setting=Setting::all();

    View::share('setting', $setting);

}
```

So you can access `$setting` in any view

Answer (score 0):

1. `php artisan make:provider GlobalShareDataProvider`
2. Go into Providers/AppServiceProvider.php and register into the **register** method just like below

```
$this->app->register(GlobalShareDataProvider::class);
```

3. Inside the boot method of **GlobalShareDataProvider** write your own business logic to get the data that will be available in all views.

   ```
   public function boot(){

     /* add your business logic here */
     $data = DB::table('users')->get();
     View::share([
         'users'=>$data,
         'country'=>'pakistan'
     ]);
   }
   ```

Now I can access all this data in all views.

Cheers !

Comment: Correction: no need to make it complex (for point 2) when you can directly add your service provider in `config/app.php` => `providers`... No need to register it in `AppServiceProvider`...

Comment: And clean code is to register it in `config/app.php` as that is the Laravel way, you register in `AppServiceProvider` services that require a logic to be loaded or not, else always in the config file

Comment: @matiaslauriti Please go through the offical laravel docs and let me know if you can see the method you are talking about .

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: The approach that i use give you more control on code re usability and better organizing the expensive logic. Registering in config/app.php is no issue but we usually register the 3rd Party package Provider in app.php so that in case of project migration user just need to update the composer and everything will setup properly.

Comment: Sharing this data using `View` as you did is okay, what I am talking about is point number `2`, read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers#registering-providers)